# .split("\") is not working and also an error arrayIndexOitOfBoundsException: 1

Tags: java, netbeans

```
String dateofbirth = ((JTextField)jDateChooser1.getDateEditor().getUiComponent()).getText();
        System.out.println(""+dateofbirth);

        String [] dob= dateofbirth.split("/");
       System.out.println(""+dob[0]);
       System.out.println(""+dob[1]);
       System.out.println(""+dob[2]);
```

Comment: which is correct: title with backslash or code with forward slash? and why are you adding `dateofbirth` to an empty string {in a println}?   and doesn't `JDateChooser.getDate()` return the chosen date? (I do not know which class that is)

Comment: Could you provide an example of the string you are obtaining for `dateofbirth`? Also, it is `.split("\");` or `.split("/")` that's not working? The first one,  `.split("\");` is not going to work because you are escaping `"`. It should be  `.split("\\");`

Answer (score 0):

You need to check dateofbirth is correct format, and prevent exception by check length of array.

```
String [] dob= dateofbirth.split("/");

if(dob != null && dob.length >=3){
       System.out.println(""+dob[0]);
       System.out.println(""+dob[1]);
       System.out.println(""+dob[2]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use array index out of bound exception try catch.

```
try {
      String [] dob= dateofbirth.split("/");
       System.out.println(""+dob[0]);
       System.out.println(""+dob[1]);
       System.out.println(""+dob[2])

catch(ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException exception) {
    handleTheExceptionSomehow(exception);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

seems like the array dob is having only one element and there is no index 1 in it. That is why you see `java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1`
The index start from 0.

Use looping to navigate the array so that you can dynamically handle your use case based on the array size. To give an example, see below.

**Example**

```
        String input = "abc/def/ghi/jkl";
        String[] matrix = input.split("/");

        /* Print each letter of the string array in a separate line. */
        for(int i = 0; i < matrix.length; ++i) {
             System.out.println(matrix[i]);
        }
```

This will give output like,

```
abc
def
ghi
jkl
```

This way you can avoid encountering `java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException:`